# PythonNameError: name 'discovery' is not defined

Tags: python, zabbix, pingdom

Have this below function.But getting error ..any thoughts ?

```
def zabbix_discovery(pingdom_data):
        discovery = []
        for k,v in data["recipes"].items():
                discovery.append(
                         {"{#NAME}": str(v['name'])}
                         )
cmd_args = [
        'zabbix_sender',
        '-z', config.get('ZABBIX', 'server'),
        '-p', config.get('ZABBIX', 'port'),
        '-s', config.get('ZABBIX', 'host'),
        '-k', config.get('ZABBIX', 'key1'),
        '-o', "'{ \"data\": " + discovery + " }'"
        ]
zabbix_trapper(cmd_args)
```

=====

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "txncheck_backup.py", line 52, in <module>
    '-o', "'{ \"data\": " + discovery + " }'"
NameError: name 'discovery' is not defined
```

=====

Comment: You've forgotten to ask a question. Anyway, `discovery` will only be available in the scope it's defined in. You'll have to `return` a value, for instance...

Comment: Sorry ..How do I return it ? dose "return discovery" will work ?

Comment: You can remove `pingdom_data` as it isn't used anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You are using `discovery` before it is declared on the function call.

Also, as you declare it in the function, it will be destroyed at the end of it and wont be available in the main scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access it before you call the function `zabbix_discovery` which assigns value to it. Even if you did correct this logical mistake, you still would not be able to access the `discovery` variable because it is a local variable. You can either add `return discovery` to the end of the function and then `discovery = zabbix_discovery(pingdom_data)`, or make it a global variable. Former would look somewhat like this:

```
discovery = []
def zabbix_discovery(pingdom_data):
    global discovery
    do what you want to do with it
zabbix_discovery(args)
```

Also even when you fix these things your code will throw another error because you are trying to access dictionary `data` in your function, which has no value assigned too. If it is assigned somewhere outside the function, you can easily fix that by adding `global data` in the beginning of your function.

And why do you have `pingdom_data` as an argument in your function if you don't use it anywhere?